# Imprimir linha da tabela "dataTable"

Tags: javascript, java, jpa

Estou usando Java,JPA,Wildfly e Primefaces.
Tenho uma tabela com varias colunas e linhas, como faço para imprimir(relatório)cada linha da tabela?
cada linha possuira o seu ícone de impressao e gostaria de saber como faço para mandar cada linha pra impressora.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o componente **p:dataExporter** do PrimeFaces. Ele te possibilita exportar facilmente os dados de uma datatable para os formatos EXCEL, PDF, CSV e XML.

Segue um exemplo de sua utilização no site do PrimeFaces:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/basic.xhtml

O PDF possui uma formatação bem simples, mas é possível configurar algumas coisas básicas programaticamente, como margem e orientação:

```java
public static void formatarRelatorioPdf(Document pdf) {
    pdf.setMarginMirroringTopBottom(false);
    pdf.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    pdf.setMargins(-102, -102, 2, 2);
}
```

Obs.: A classe com.lowagie.text.Document pertence à lib **itext**.

Para fazer documentos PDF mais elaborados, você pode fazê-los utilizando Jasper Reports e iText ou fazê-los em HTML. De ambas as maneiras será necessário pesquisa e um pouco de estudo, mas o resultado fica ótimo. Recomendo a primeira opção porque relatórios em HTML algumas vezes fica com alguma diferença entre os bowsers.

Espero que tenha ajudado!